# mySQl, Query: How to customize selection from database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have four tables:

```
courses, allocate_rooms, rooms, departments
```

Query:

```
SELECT
    courses.`name`,
    courses.`code`,
    allocate_rooms.`start`,
    allocate_rooms.`end`,
    rooms.room_number
FROM
    departments
JOIN courses ON departments.id = courses.department_id
LEFT JOIN allocate_rooms ON allocate_rooms.course_id = courses.id
LEFT JOIN rooms ON allocate_rooms.room_id = rooms.id
WHERE
    departments.id = 1
```

From the Query I have to make a selection view as  rooms.room_number, allocate_rooms.start-allocate.rooms_end; and if there is no data related to that course I have to show "Not Scheduled Yet".

```
Eg: R.No: 301,12:00-12:30; (if the course related data is there otherwise it will show "Not Scheduled Yet"
```

How do I rewrite the above Query? If anybody help me to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with ifnull

```
SELECT courses.name, courses.code, allocate_rooms.start,
  allocate_rooms.end   , 
   case rooms.room_number 
         WHEN IS NULL THEN 'No Rooms allocated'
         WHEN 0 THEN 'No Rooms allocated'
         ELSE room.room_number
         end
FROM departments 
join courses on departments.id = courses.department_id 
left join allocate_rooms on allocate_rooms.course_id=courses.id 
left join rooms on allocate_rooms.room_id=rooms.id 
WHERE departments.id=1
```

Comment: How do I join the view of `rooms.room_number ,allocate_rooms.start -allocate_rooms.end;`

Comment: Explain Better i don't understand .. please

Comment: I may have to use alias for joining those columns to add while selection from database!
As I said in my Question, I need to join `allocate_rooms.start,allocate_rooms.end,rooms.room_number` and if there is no values associated to these It should show like `No Rooms allocated`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's what you need, but try this:

You can use DECODE for getting what you need.

```
SELECT
    c.name name
   ,c.code code
   ,decode(ar.start,NULL,'Not Schedule Yet') START
   ,decode(ar.end,NULL,'Not Schedule Yet') END
   ,r.room_number roomnum
FROM
    departments d
   ,courses c
   ,allocate_rooms ar
   ,rooms r
WHEREd.id = c.id
AND ar.course_id = c.id
AND ar.room_id = r.room_id
AND d.id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
SELECT courses.name, courses.code,COALESCE( CONCAT('R. No',':',rooms.room_number,', ',days.name ,', ', allocate_rooms.start,' - ',allocate_rooms.end),"Not Assigned Yet") AS Schedule 
FROM departments join courses on departments.id = courses.department_id
left join allocate_rooms on allocate_rooms.course_id=courses.id 
left join rooms on allocate_rooms.room_id=rooms.id
left join days on allocate_rooms.day_id=days.id WHERE departments.id=1
```